# Prolog removing all variables and duplicates

Tags: list, prolog

I need a query, which will remove me all **variables** and **duplicates** from list.

Example:

```
?- L = [1,2,3,X,Y,3,2], my_awesome_predicate(L, Res).
```

Then, Res should be: [1,2,3].

**I don't care about order (it could be [2,3,1], [3,2,1] or whatever).**

Unfortunately, I have a task in which I have to care about efficiency, so my main question is - can it be done faster? Currently, I have the following code:

```
remove_variables([], []).
remove_variables([H|List], Res):- var(H), !, remove_variables(List, Res).
remove_variables([H|List], [H|Res]):- remove_variables(List, Res).

my_awesome_predicate([], []).
my_awesome_predicate(List, Res):-
  sort(List, Sorted),
  remove_variables(Sorted, Res).
```

Comment: well, you have optimal complexity. faster can only be done with hash maps. How long are your lists anyway?

Comment: You should rename the result variable in your example - right now your `X` is both a variable in `L` and the output argument of your predicate; I don't think that's what you intended.

Comment: @WillNess How can I do this with hash maps? These lists are very short (up to 10 elements), I am calling this predicate huge amount of times.

Comment: You can remove variables first (since you don't care about them), then call `sort`. (Reverse the order) Since the list is short, there is not much you can do to speed it up.

Comment: if the lists are so short, try my answer. it may get optimized better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** you are using *SWI* then you can improve a little further with this code:

```
my_awesome_predicate(List, Res):-
  sort(List, MRes),
  remove_variables(MRes, Res).

remove_variables([Var|Tail], NTail):-
  var(Var),
  !,
  remove_variables(Tail, NTail).
remove_variables(Res, Res).
```

as it seems that SWI's sort will leave unbounded variables first (don't know if this behavior is a standard among other prolog's), so you can stop removing variables once you find the first non-variable.

Reading a bit [SWI's documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%274.7.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/compare.html%27%29%29), it's stated that:

```
4.7.1 Standard Order of Terms

Comparison and  unification of arbitrary  terms.   Terms are ordered  in
the so called ``standard order''.  This order is defined as follows:

 1. Variables < Numbers < Atoms < Strings < Compound Terms
```

so it seems safe to stop removing elements when you find the first non-variable...

Answer (score 1):

```
awesome([],[]).
awesome([H|T],R):- var(H), !, awesome(T,R).
awesome([H|T],R):- awesome(T,[H],R).

awesome([],R,R).
awesome([H|T],A,R):- memberchk(H,A) -> awesome(T,A,R) ; awesome(T,[H|A],R).
```

Something like this? Theoretically it is quadratic, but your lists are very short and this code is very simple, so might get optimized by the compiler better.

If you append your resulting lists, better change it to work with difference lists, putting the output directly into the resulting list being built:

```
awesome([],Z,Z).
awesome([H|T],R,Z):- var(H), !, awesome(T,R,Z).
awesome([H|T],R,Z):- R=[H|Y], awesome(T,[H],Y,Z).

awesome([],_,Z,Z).
awesome([H|T],A,R,Z):- memberchk(H,A) -> awesome(T,A,R,Z) 
                                      ;  R=[H|Y], awesome(T,[H|A],Y,Z).
```

[`memberchk/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=memberchk%2F2) of course weeds out variables as well as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for the reference there is another nice and short solution using `setof`.

```
my_awesome_predicate(L, Res) :-
    setof(X, (member(X, L), ground(X)), Res).
```

`Res` contains the solution without variables with the terms ordered by their first appearance.

```
?- my_awesome_predicate([1,2,3,X,Y,3,2], Res).
Res = [1, 2, 3].
```